# Binding adapter with multiple arguments in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

To use multiple arguments for a data binding adapter the Java syntax is

```
@BindingAdapter(value={"arg1", "arg2"}, requireAll = false)
```

However this does not compile in Kotlin:

```
Error:(13, 37) Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

what's the correct syntax for multiple arguments in Kotlin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Should be:

```
@BindingAdapter(value=*arrayOf("arg1", "arg2"), requireAll = false)
```

Please refer to the official annotations [docs for Java Annotations in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#java-annotations)

Quoting:

> For other arguments that have an array type, you need to use arrayOf explicitly:

```
// Java
public @interface AnnWithArrayMethod {
    String[] names();
}


// Kotlin
@AnnWithArrayMethod(names = arrayOf("abc", "foo", "bar")) class C
```

**EDIT:** Credit to @Francesc

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is actually slightly different,
@BindingAdapter(value= *arrayOf("arg1", "arg2"), requireAll = false)

Comment: Please note that `requireAll` argument must be set explicitly, that was the problem in my case

Answer (score 8):

Or you can just simply do this

```
@BindingAdapter("arg1", "agr2", "agr3", "agr4", requireAll = false)
```

as pointed in  [Android Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters)

Answer (score 5):

From Kotlin 1.2 you can do

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["arg1", "arg2"], requireAll = false)
```

Comment: can you specifiy a source?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by this way:

```
@BindingAdapter(value= ["deckBackgroundAsFirstParameter", "typeAsSecondParameter"], requireAll = false) 
fun loadBackgroundMethodNameForExample(imageViewForExample: ImageView, deckBackgroundAsFirstParameter: Int?, typeAsSecondParameter: Int?) {
   ...
}
```

where **value** is an array of the parameters that you want to use.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.